# Office 365 Personal - Hotmail domain - REST API - Error : no mailbox associated

Tags: office365

I bought one **Office 365 Personal** account and linked it with my already existing hotmail email account. So now using hotmail ID , I can sing-in to Office 365 and use the products.

Now I am trying to access **Calendar REST APIs** as explained in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations).

If I try:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/myemail@hotmail.com/calendarview?startDateTime=01/01/2000&endDateTime=01/01/2014
```

Then it gives:

> {
>   error: 
>   { code: "ErrorNonExistentMailbox", message: "The SMTP address
>   has no mailbox associated with it." }
>   }

and If I try:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events
```

then:

> {
>
> error: { code: "ErrorMissingEmailAddress", message: "When making a
>   request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify
>   the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids." }
>
> }

and if I try:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/myemail@hotmail.com
```

then:

> { 
>   error: { code: "ErrorInternalServerError", message: "Invalid value
>   for arg:smtpAddress, value:" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Office 365 APIs don't support Office 365 Personal accounts.